# How to connect two pc in a subnet in two different location?

Tags: networking, routing

I have a client which have a LAN in his office (point A) and have his file server in another (different) location (point B).
Question: 
We want to make a connection between points A & B that look like they are in one sub net to make users in the point A can access their database at the point B. 
condtions:
-In the point A we have a static IP (provided by ISP)
-In the point B we cant have static IP but we can use a Dyndns Service instead.
-We are running a SQL server database on point B which is using by user at point A.
Now please give me a solution to connect these points.

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a false premise. Accessing a database or a fileserver does not generally require being in the same subnet.

Comment: so give me a solution to connect my file server at the mentioned conditions without using the same subnet.

Comment: By default accessing database dose not require being in the same subnet, you right, but in my situation, my client uses a software that checks for LAN subnet and routing so my first (maybe even) choice is to use both lan in the same subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to look like you're in the same subnet, you should have a layer-2 connection. All ISPs that I know only provide layer-3 connections. If you want the same subnet, you should build a tunnel over your L3 connections.

Depending on the requirements and the available hardware, that could be anything from a GRE tunnel, to an IPSec or OpenVPN tunnel. Judging from the question, I would suggest investgating an OpenVPN tunnel. Having a static IP makes it easier to connect.

Comment: I think it can be happen by using cloud in Mikrotik routers instead of VPN. where VPN tunnel slow down the bandwidth.

Comment: Possibly; haven't played with Mikrotik. What I see of the Mikrotik cloud is mostly L3 though. But also for that cloud, you will need some tunnel.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to configure a mikrotik cloud? Actually I bought 2 Mikrotik 951-UI2hnd and prepare to set them up. by the way in comparison which one is better? Mikrotik cloud or VPN tunnel with L2TP and IPSEC?

Comment: As I said, I haven't played with Mikrotik. And it depends a lot on your traffic: if you need to encrypt, IPSec is an option, even though it is complicated to set up. Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol does exactly what you asked, but not more. And about the Mikrotik cloud, I just don't know.

Comment: Thank you Ljm, finally I setup my routers with L2TP and used IPSEC for encryption. It was as hard as I thought, however having Static IP in one side made problem for me. I think using dynamic IP for this job male better performance,. and setting up the routers will be easier.

Comment: Final word is as the  grawity mentioned in the first answer using the same subnet for 2 sides is not necessary but also using different subnets will be better to decrease vpn  tunnel traffic.